# Select query in LINQ based on Foreign Table

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, linq

I have 2 Tables , OrderDetails and Requests In my LINQ to SQL dbml file.
OrderDetailsID is a foreign key in Requests Table.

I want to write the query to get the sum of UnitCost from OrderDetails based on OrderId.
And If there is a row in Requests Table for each OrderDetailsID, and the Requests.Last.RequestType="Refund" I want to reduce the total refund amount from the main sum otherwise If there is no row based on OrderDetailsID, add to sum.

Here is the way I implement that.
I am looking to prevent using "For each".

Any Solutions?

```
 iRefund = (From od1 In dc.OrderDetails _
            Where od1.OrderID =1  _
            Select od1.UnitCost).Sum

 Dim objOrderDetails = (From od1 In dc.OrderDetails _
                       Where od1.OrderID =1  _
                       Select od1)

 For Each OrderDetail As ORM.Entities.OrderDetail In objOrderDetails
     If Not OrderDetail.Requests Is Nothing Then
         IF OrderDetail.Requests.Last.RequestType="Refund" Then
                   iRefund -= OrderDetail.UnitCost
         End If
     End If  
  Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Linq instead of a for-each loop, you could use the ForEach extension method of List:

```
Dim objOrderDetails = (From od1 In dc.OrderDetails _
                       Where od1.OrderId = 1 _
                       Select od1).ToList()

objOrderDetails.ForEach(AddressOf DecrementAmount)
```

---

```
Private Sub DecrementAmount(ByVal d As OrderDetail)
    If d.Requests IsNot Nothing _
        AndAlso d.Requests.Count > 0 _
        AndAlso d.Requests.Last.RequestType = "Refund" Then
        iRefund -= d.UnitCost
    End If
End Sub
```

This assumes that iRefund is a module variable.

Comment: I look forward to find out If there is a solution to merge the select query and ForEach and get the result by using one LINQ query. But thx for your response. It was helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by merge? You can chain the two statements and thus skip declaring objOrderDetails, but you can't do away with ToList() because ForEach() is not available on IQueryable or even IEnumerable.